# How do I view the reason why a deployment failed in JBoss 7?

Tags: logging, deployment, jboss, log4j, jboss7.x

I’m using JBoss 7.1.3.Final with Java 6.  I’m trying to deploy my exploded web application project and I get this very non-descriptive error …

```
15:26:51,187 INFO  [stdout] (MSC service thread 1-1) [DEBUG,EntityManagerFactoryRegistry] Remove: name=default
15:26:51,245 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (MSC service thread 1-1) Initializing Mojarra 2.1.11-jbossorg-3 20120815-1456 for context '/myproject'
15:26:56,631 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-1) Error listenerStart
15:26:56,641 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-1) Context [/myproject] startup failed due to previous errors
15:26:56,671 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./myproject: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./myproject: JBAS018040: Failed to start context
        at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:94)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895) [rt.jar:1.6.0_65]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918) [rt.jar:1.6.0_65]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680) [rt.jar:1.6.0_65]

15:26:56,922 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) JBAS018559: Deployed "myproject.war"
15:26:56,923 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 28) JBAS018559: Deployed "jenkins.war"
15:26:56,925 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014774: Service status report
```

JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./myproject: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./myproject: JBAS018040: Failed to start context

There is no other stack trace before or after this error.  What kind of logging do I need to enable to get more information about why my deployment failed?  I have this log4j.properties in my WEB-INF/classes file …

```
# Global logging configuration
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout

# Console output...
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.conversionPattern=[%p,%c{1}] %m%n

# Rolling log file output...
log4j.appender.fileout=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.fileout.File=myproject.log
log4j.appender.fileout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.fileout.layout.conversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1},%t:%L - %m%n
log4j.appender.fileout.Append=false

# package specific logging
log4j.logger.net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICachePeer=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.springframework.security=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.collegeboard.springboard.myproject.mvc.listener=DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.collegeboard.springboard.core.security=DEBUG
```

and here is how my logging is set up in $JBOSS_HOME/standalone/configuration/standlone.xml file …

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:1.1">
        <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
            <level name="INFO"/>
            <formatter>
                <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
            </formatter>
        </console-handler>
        <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE">
            <formatter>
                <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
            </formatter>
            <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
            <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
            <append value="true"/>
        </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
        <logger category="com.arjuna">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="sun.rmi">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="jacorb">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="jacorb.config">
            <level name="ERROR"/>
        </logger>
        <root-logger>
            <level name="INFO"/>
            <handlers>
                <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
                <handler name="FILE"/>
            </handlers>
        </root-logger>
    </subsystem>
```

Comment: That stack trace is the only you got?

Comment: This is last error log after failed deployment but if you will scroll up in server logs you can see exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

try to add this JVM parameter:

```
-Dorg.jboss.as.logging.per-deployment=false
```